# Solve Infinite Recursion in c#

Tags: c#, recursion, stack-overflow, callstack

I know I'm having an infinite recursion problem in my code with a stack overflow. I just don't know how to go about fixing it, help would be appreciated.

```
public Point WorldToMapCell(Point worldPoint)
{
    return WorldToMapCell(new Point((int)worldPoint.X, (int)worldPoint.Y));
}

public MapCell GetCellAtWorldPoint(Point worldPoint)
{
    Point mapPoint = WorldToMapCell(worldPoint);
    return Rows[mapPoint.Y].Columns[mapPoint.X];
}

public MapCell GetCellAtWorldPoint(Vector2 worldPoint)
{
    return GetCellAtWorldPoint(new Point((int)worldPoint.X, (int)worldPoint.Y));
}
```

Comment: You need a way to terminate! Usually a base case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Infinite recursion (and the resulting stack overflow) happens when you've got a function that directly, or indirectly, calls itself repeatedly without any opportunity for it to stop doing that. Your first function, `WorldToMapCell` calls itself unconditionally, causing this problem.

Comment: So, I would have to put a condition on the return?

Comment: Well, I wouldn't necessarily say that. What is `WorldToMapCell` supposed to do? Is it supposed to call itself (which doesn't really make sense), or is it supposed to call some other function? Do you even *need* this function at all?

Answer (score 2):

In order for recursion to work, your method must have a base case. Otherwise, it will get stuck in an infinite loop of calling itself.

Consider the case of calculating the factorial of a number:

```
public int factorial(int x) {
    if (x == 0)
        return 1;
    else 
        return x * factorial(x - 1);
```

In order for the recursion to work, the factorial method approaches the base case, where x = 0. In your method, you make no steps towards a base case, and thus, your method will continue to call itself forever.

Comment: While this answer is true, I don't think it relates to the original problem in the question much at all.

Answer (score 2):

```
public Point WorldToMapCell(Point worldPoint)
{
    return WorldToMapCell(new Point((int)worldPoint.X, (int)worldPoint.Y));
}
```

This method will recurse infinitely itself. (It calls itself over and over again).

From what I can tell, this method should return a new point with the co-ords of the worldpoint parameter, if thats the case it should look like this:

```
public Point WorldToMapCell(Point worldPoint)
{
    return new Point((int)worldPoint.X, (int)worldPoint.Y);
}
```

You do not need to call the method, but instead just directly return the new point.